# Is it possible to access the raw audio data in webRTC?

Tags: webrtc, html5-audio

I am looking for a way to use the audio channel to deliver some random data that will then be processed on the client side which would be possible only if I can access the raw audio. Is there a way to do it?

I know that the alternative and proper way to do this is to use the data channel, but I think that the latency would be higher than when using the audio channel.

Comment: You *think* so? Why? Have you measured it?

Comment: Not yet, but I am considering every option at this stage before running tests

Comment: Data channels are using the same P2P transport as audio or video channels, there should be no significant delay.